# Why doesn't it short-circuit when you multiply the return value of a function by zero?

Tags: c++, return, lazy-evaluation, short-circuiting

Consider a function like the below:

```cpp
unsigned int fact(unsigned int i) {
    if (i <= 1) { return 1; }
    return i * fact(i-1);
}
```

If I were to instantiate a new variable `unsigned int f` such that `f = 0 * fact(5)`, why does it not "short circuit"?

```cpp
unsigned int fact(unsigned int i) {
    std::cout << "a";
    if (i <= 1) { return 1; }
    return i * fact(i-1);
}

int main() {
    unsigned int f = 0 * fact(5);
}
```

The output here is `aaaaa`. If `f` can only ever be zero, why would it call the function at all, supposing it knew the return type? Does it not evaluate left to right, see `0 * (unsigned int)` and know the rvalue will be `0`?

Comment: The language requires that all operands be evaluated before applying the operation. Only logic operator (`&&` and `||`) perform short-circuit in C++.

Comment: Did you check the optimized code generated for main if you removing the printing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short-circuit evaluation is mandatory for `&&` (logical *and*), `||` (logical *or*) and `?` (ternary operator). For the remaining operators it is an (optional) optimization.

The evaluation of `fact(5)` in the expression `0 * fact(5)` can't be in general optimized away just because you know that the outcome of the whole expression is `0` since a call to `fact()` may introduce side effects (e.g., modify some global variable), so it must be called.

As said in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59504387/why-doesnt-it-short-circuit-when-you-multiply-the-return-value-of-a-function-by/59504462#comment105181335_59504462), a good compiler will optimize away the call to `fact(5)` if it can prove that there are no side effects.

Comment: A good compiler _will_ elide the call to `fact` if it can prove it has no side-effects.  For example, GCC [does so](https://godbolt.org/z/QUGXsg) for OP's example if the `cout` is removed.

Comment: The discussion about side-effects is bit of a distraction, since short-circuited `||`/`&&` operands can be elided regardless of side-effects.

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0 Thanks, I've edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

> Does it not evaluate left to right, see 0 * (unsigned int) and know the rvalue will be 0?

It could, and it would if the standard told it to.

But it doesn't.

Short-circuiting simply isn't a thing for multiplication. They could have made it a thing, but it would arguably have been confusing.

We're all used to `f() || g()` potentially skipping the call to `g()`, but would you really expect `0 * g()` to do the same thing? Particularly since `0` is just one out of *billions* of possible integers? It would be an oddly specific feature. (By contrast `true` is one out of only two boolean values.)

This isn't about side effects, because the side effects of `g()` would be skipped by `f() || g()` if `f()` returns `true`. That's just how it is.

In practice, a compiler *could* elide the call to `g()` in `0 * g()` if it knew that `g()` had no side-effects (so the program's behaviour wouldn't be changed), but that's not short-circuiting; that's ["optimisation"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59456112/560648).

Comment: 0 is not just one of a billion integers when we're talking multiplication.  It forms the same structure as `false` does for logical and, and `true` for or.

Comment: @xtofl What do you mean "same structure"?

Comment: It 'feels' like zero is to multiplication what `false` is to conjunction.  My algebra isn't good enough to state it better.

Comment: I suppose I can see what you mean