# GLM library deprecation warnings around volatile in C++20

Tags: c++, floating-point, c++20, volatile, glm-math

Many operations with volatile were deprecated in c++20 (see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv)

So.... when I used very popular glm library(https://github.com/g-truc/glm) in my project I got warnings around this code (file `type_half.inl`):

```
GLM_FUNC_QUALIFIER float overflow()
{
    volatile float f = 1e10;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        f *= f; // this will overflow before the for loop terminates
    return f;
}
```

This code used to force causing floating point overflow, and obviously volatile here used to turn off optimization around f. Otherwise compiler can just throw out this cycle as useless.

How this code may be fixed for modern standards of c++, like c++20 and above?

Comment: Turn off the warning?  (The compiler should tell you what flag to use on the command line)

Comment: you can replace the usage of volatile using std:atomic

Comment: Turning off the warnings - is very bad practice!!  It's absolutely not an option.
@PaulSanders

Comment: std:atomic - heavyweight for this, as addition there is no need any thread safety or barriers

Comment: Check this out and throw the volatile away, it was never safe to use it to disable optimisations. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40122141/preventing-compiler-optimizations-while-benchmarking

Also, the implementation of DoNotOptimize of google/benchmark might interest you: https://github.com/google/benchmark/blob/main/include/benchmark/benchmark.h

Comment: _Turning off the warnings - is very bad practice!! It's absolutely not an option._ You would only do it for the files that need it...  See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378560/how-to-disable-gcc-warnings-for-a-few-lines-of-code

Comment: @fsmoke: Is there some reason the function doesn't just return `numeric_limits<float>::infinity()`, since that's what happens when you overflow an IEEE-754 float?

Comment: @EricPostpischil, warning: compound assignment with ‘volatile’-qualified left operand is deprecated [-Wvolatile]

Comment: @NicolBolas, it seems return value of this function always discarded - this functions used only for cause float overflow(i.e. generate FPU exception if such option is turned on)

Comment: *"Turning off the warnings - is very bad practice"* Dealing with absolutes is bad practice. I wouldn't disable it globally, yes, but disabling it for a specific file or lines is ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious solution is to remove the `*=`: `f = f * f;`. The code doesn't specifically need any special behavior out of `*=`; it just wants to make the compiler not optimize the multiplying operations. To the extent that `volatile` makes the compiler do that, it would work just as well with `f = f * f;`.

Comment: YES this works!! warnings now suppressed! Thanx

Comment: @fsmoke: You should submit this to the GLM Github repo as an issue/pull request.

Comment: yes i think tomorrow(now evening - i already tired) i'll create new pull-request to glm repo

Comment: hahaha - i just now clone master branch of glm - and there this warning already fixed - as you suggest f = f * f :)))) - so... all already done, without us

Comment: "*The obvious solution*"  Can you explain the obvious part? I may have a wrong mental model regarding the difference of the two expressions (none for trivial types like `float`)

Comment: @MatG: I don't understand. You seem to recognize that there is no difference between the two expressions in this instance, save the fact that one is legal and the other is legal-but-deprecated. So... use the legal one. That's the obvious part. The whole point of deprecating `*=` and its ilk on `volatile` is to make it clear that you know that it isn't a single atomic operation. `f = f * f;` makes that clear in a way that `f *= f;` does not.

Comment: @MatG, difference between operations is: f*=f this operation on lvalue - deprecated, but f=f*f direct assignment - legal by new standard. Reread cppreference more careful in my start post