# Avoid optimizing away variable with inline asm

Tags: c++, assembly, performance-testing, compiler-optimization, inline-assembly

I was reading [Preventing compiler optimizations while benchmarking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40122141/preventing-compiler-optimizations-while-benchmarking) that describes how `clobber()` and `escape()` from Chandler Carruths talk  [CppCon 2015: Chandler Carruth "Tuning C++: Benchmarks, and CPUs, and Compilers! Oh My!"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nXaxk27zwlk) affects the compiler.

From reading that, I assumed that if I have an input constraint like "g"(`val`), then the compiler wouldn't be able to optimize away `val`. But in `g()` below, no code is generated. Why?

How can `doNotOptimize()` be rewritten to ensure code is generated for `g()`?

```
template <typename T>
void doNotOptimize(T const& val) {
  asm volatile("" : : "g"(val) : "memory");
}

void f() {
  char x = 1;
  doNotOptimize(&x);    // x is NOT optimized away
}

void g() {
  char x = 1;
  doNotOptimize(x);     // x is optimized away
}
```

https://godbolt.org/g/Ndd56K

Comment: I would say, because `g` passes the value as const ref to `doNotOptimize`  the compiler is allowed to assume that `x` or better `val` must not change, so it can optimize the call away. `f` on the other hand passes a const pointer to `doNotOptimize` so `x` could indeed change.

Comment: Related Q&As about the same functions: [Preventing compiler optimizations while benchmarking](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40122141) / [I don't understand the definition of DoNotOptimizeAway](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52203710) / ["Escape" and "Clobber" equivalent in MSVC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33975479)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What, exactly, would it mean to have code generated for g()? If you were writing it yourself, what code would you write? Seriously, this is a real question. You have to decide what output you're expecting before you can start cajoling it from the compiler.

Anyway, let's look at what you have now. In f(),

```
void f() {
  char x = 1;
  doNotOptimize(&x);    // x is NOT optimized away
}
```

you are taking the *address* of `x`, which prevents the optimizer from allocating it in a register. It has to be allocated in memory in order for it to have an address.

However, in g(),

```
void g() {
  char x = 1;
  doNotOptimize(x);     // x is optimized away
}
```

`x` is just a local variable and any sane optimizer will allocate that in a register, or in this case as a constant. This is allowed, since you never take its address; you just use its value. So, for example, the compiler might generate code like this:

```
g():
    mov  al, 1      // store 1 in BYTE-sized register AL
    ...
```

Or as in this case not generate any code at all, and substitute any use of the variable by it's constant value.

Your `doNotOptimize` code,

```
template <typename T>
void doNotOptimize(T const& val) {
  asm volatile("" : : "g"(val) : "memory");
}
```

uses the `g` constraint for the `val` parameter, which says that it can be stored in *either* a general-purpose register, memory *or* as a constant, whichever the optimizer finds most convenient. Since `val` is a constant, when this call is inlined, the optimizer leaves it as a constant. Your "memory" clobber specifier has no effect, because there is no modification of memory going on here.

So what can we do? Well, we can force the variable `x` to be allocated in memory, even though it doesn't need to be, by using the `m` constraint:

```
template <typename T>
void doNotOptimize(T const& val) {
  asm volatile("" : : "m"(val) : "memory");
}

void g() {
  char x = 1;
  doNotOptimize(x);
}
```

Now the compiler can't optimize the store of `x` away and is forced to emit the following code:

```
g():
    mov  BYTE PTR [rsp-1], 1
    ret
```

Note that this is basically the same effect that declaring the `x` variable `volatile` would have.

Remember the question I asked at the beginning? Is that the output you wanted?

Or, maybe you want the compiler to emit that immediate-to-register move. If so, the `r` constraint will work—or [any of the x86-specific constraints](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html) that allow you to dictate a particular register. This forces the optimizer to allocate the value in a register, even though it doesn't need to be:

```
g():
    mov     eax, 1
    ret
```

I cannot, however, see what the point of either of these would be.

If you wanted to craft a microbenchmark that tested the overhead of calling a function with a single const-reference parameter, then a better option would be to ensure that the definition of the function being called is not visible to the optimizer. Then, it can't inline that function and *has* to arrange for the call to be made, including all necessary setup. This also works well if you're just [studying how a compiler might emit that code](https://godbolt.org/g/f00JHd). (Naturally, you can't use a template function, though. Well, unless you wanted to [abuse C++11's `extern` templates](https://godbolt.org/g/CDEVcK).)

Comment: I  had the fuzzy notion that the doNotOptimize() function should work regardless of the input parameter being a pointer or not. As to the meaning of the asm constraints, I hadn't understood them. BTW, I noticed that Facebooks folly library do have template specializations for different types. I rewrote my example using their doNotOptimizeAway: https://godbolt.org/g/C8OvGm

Comment: You sometimes want to use `"+r"(var)` alongside this, to tell trick the compiler into re-computing something inside a loop.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to declare

```
volatile char x = 1;
```

But notice that the compiler is "right" to optimize like you observe.

Answer (score 0):

No code is generated for `g()` because the `"g"` constraint allows the input to be optimised to a constant.